# EEA Family permit - for parent

Tags: customs-and-immigration, family

I am an Italian national living in the UK since 2006. My dad is of Sri Lankan nationality with a permesso di soggiorno where he has permanent residence in Italy. Can he apply for EEA family permit? Anybody has done similar like this?

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on whether your parent is **dependent** on you or not.

Since you have been living separately since 2006, you would probably have to show that his situation now has changed making his living with you essential.

---

> **[EU Settlement Scheme family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eu-settlement-scheme-family-permit)**
> **Qualifying as a ‘close’ family member**
> You must be the EEA citizen’s spouse or civil partner, or related to them (or to their spouse or civil partner) as their:
>
> - child or grandchild under 21 years old, or dependent child or grandchild of any age
> - **dependent parent** or grandparent

---

**Sources**:

- [Apply for a permit to join your EU or EEA family member in the UK: EU Settlement Scheme family permit - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eu-settlement-scheme-family-permit)

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they live together or plan to live together.  If the parent is financially dependent then he will qualify.

Answer (score 1):

[The requirements for applying](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit) are as follows:

> ## EEA family permit
>
> You can apply for an EEA family permit to come to the UK if both the following apply:
>
> - you’re from outside the European Economic Area (EEA)
> - you’re a ‘close’ or ‘extended’ family member of an EEA or Swiss national (excluding UK nationals)

Since Sri Linka is not in the European Economic Area, your dad meets the first requirement.

As for the second requirement, there are specific rules as to what qualifies as a 'close' or 'extended' family member:

> ## Qualifying as a ‘close’ family member
>
> You must be the EEA citizen’s spouse or civil partner, or related to
> them (or to their spouse or civil partner) as their:
>
> - child or grandchild under 21 years old, or dependent child or grandchild of any age
> - dependent parent or grandparent

So your dad has to be your dependent parent or grandparent to qualify.

To be eligible, you must meet other requirements as you have been living in the UK for more than 3 months:

> **If they’ve been in the UK for more than 3 months they must either:**
>
> - be a ‘qualified person’ (working, looking for work, self-employed, studying or self-sufficient)
> - have a [permanent residence document](https://www.gov.uk/uk-residence-eu-citizens/permanent-residence) - sometimes called a ‘document certifying permanent residence’

If you don't meet any of thise two requirements for some reason, your dad must apply for the EU Settlement Scheme:

> If your family member is not a ‘qualified person’ and does not have a permanent residence document, you may be eligible for an [EU Settlement Scheme family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eu-settlement-scheme-family-permit) instead.

Comment: "your dad has to be your dependent parent or grandparent to qualify": a parent or grandparent who is not dependent may still be able to qualify as an extended family member.